# div box inside div box. Relative positioning, and equal padding, space between all sides

Tags: html, css

I have this div box right now:

```
div#main-edit{
    padding:2px 6px 4px 6px; 
    color: #555555; 
    background-color: #FFF8F8; 
    border: #dddddd 2px solid;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%; 
}
```

What I wanted now was to have another div box inside this div box, with its position being relative to its parent. Like This: [image: l]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your second div `height: 100%`, and give your outer div padding all around.

http://jsfiddle.net/P2VGk/